# Does an object initialize automatically if it is the synthesized property of another object?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, synthesize, declared-property

When you have one object as a property of another object in Objective-C, does it automatically initialize when you use `@synthesize`?

Comment: your object should be stored as a pointer, which will be initialised to `nil`

Answer (score 4):

> does it automatically initialize when you use `@synthesize`?

Yes, it is initialized to `nil` (no actual object is **allocated,** however - this is pointer initialization in the C sense of the word, the `init` method is **not** called).

By the way, you don't even have to `@synthesize` to achieve this behavior - every instance variable, even those which don't have a corresponding `@property`, are automatically initialized either to `nil` (in case of objects), `NULL` (in case of other pointers) or `0` (in case of integers and floating-point numbers) by the Objective-C runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try it:

```
@interface TypicalObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *numberProperty;

@end


@implementation TypicalObject

@synthesize numberProperty;

@end

...

TypicalObject *object = [[TypicalObject alloc] init];
NSLog(@"object.numberProperty = %@", object.numberProperty);
```

The log statement yields:

```
object.numberProperty = (null)
```

So, no, properties do not auto-instantiate. All object instance variables begin as `nil`, however.

Answer (score 0):

No. The @synthesize does not know how to initialize it. Simple `-init`?

You can allocate and initialize it in the `-init…` of the referring object.

Answer (score -1):

You still have to init. Try using lazy initialization:

```
-(MyPropertyClass*)propertyName {
if(!propertyIvarName) {
    _propertyIvarName = [[MyPropertyClass alloc] init];
}
return propertyIvarName;
}
```

or init the property in `viewdidload`

Comment: This pattern is dangerous in some scenarios, because the property can never be set to nil.

Comment: This can also lead to problems, if the property is called from multiple threads.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` doesn't apply to things which aren't views…